# HTML5 Audio element's readyState

Tags: html5-audio

Once the HTML5 audio element has reached the readyState to 4 and after that when we seek it to a different position that's not even buffered yet. Will the readyState property can go to a lesser value like 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState), there are 5 possible values of `readyState`. For the values you concerned (0 or 1), it will only appear when the content starts loading.

```
0 or HAVE_NOTHING : Have nothing yet
1 or HAVE_METADATA : Only metadata loaded
```

Therefore, 0 or 1 won't appear unless a new content is requested to load.

Comment: How about 2 and 3? Once the readyState reaches 4 is there any chance it goes to that value for ex. let's say the download speed got reduced after playing half of the audio

Comment: After reading the [W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#htmlmediaelement), it mentions that *It is possible for the ready state of a media element to jump between these states discontinuously. For example, the state of a media element can jump straight from HAVE_METADATA to HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA without passing through the HAVE_CURRENT_DATA and HAVE_FUTURE_DATA states.*. So, the answer is yes, it's possible to jump from 4 to 2 or 3.